# Peer Admin Card does not exists error, Unexpected end of JSON Input

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm working on Hyperledger Fabric in my Linux instance. Everything was running absolutely fine but all of a sudden when trying to run ./createPeerAdminCard.sh script, it shows me the following error:

Error: Card already exists: PeerAdmin@hlfv1
Command failed

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
Command failed

In the past, I have been using ./createPeerAdminCard.sh script without any errors or exceptions at all, and following is the flow for my sequence of steps:

1. ./stopFabric.sh
2. ./teardownFabric.sh
3. ./startFabric.sh
4. ./downloadFabric.sh
5. ./createPeerAdminCard.sh

./createPeerAdminCard.sh

If everything fine, hyperledger should show us the list of composer cards that I have generated, Instead it appears with the error of card already exists: Peeradmin@hlfv1, Error: Unexpected end of JSON Input, and whenever I try to run composer-network-install, it shows me the error of Card not found: Peeradmin@hlfv1

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the sequence seems to be wrong, you need to do:

```
./stopFabric.sh
./teardownFabric.sh
./downloadFabric.sh
```

AND THEN

```
./startFabric.sh
./fabric-dev-servers/createPeerAdminCard.sh
```

Try this.